# Newbie using recline.js and slickgrid

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

I am trying to use the quick start guide on recline.js, the grid appears crunched up with the html that I created to try and use the quickstart samples.  I have verified that all the .js paths are correct.

I can't figure out what I must be doing wrong. Please let me know what I am doing wrong with this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/underscore/1.1.6/underscore.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/backbone/0.5.1/backbone.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/mustache/0.5.0-dev/mustache.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/slickgrid/2.0.1/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/slickgrid/2.0.1/jquery.event.drag- 2.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="vendor/slickgrid/2.0.1/slick.grid.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/recline.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
  var data = [
    {id: 0, date: '2011-01-01', x: 1, y: 2, z: 3, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:52.56, lon:13.40} },
    {id: 1, date: '2011-02-02', x: 2, y: 4, z: 24, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:54.97, lon:-1.60}},
    {id: 2, date: '2011-03-03', x: 3, y: 6, z: 9, country: 'US', geo: {lat:40.00, lon:-75.5}},
    {id: 3, date: '2011-04-04', x: 4, y: 8, z: 6, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:57.27, lon:-6.20}},
    {id: 4, date: '2011-05-04', x: 5, y: 10, z: 15, country: 'UK', geo: {lat:51.58, lon:0}},
    {id: 5, date: '2011-06-02', x: 6, y: 12, z: 18, country: 'DE', geo: {lat:51.04, lon:7.9}}
  ];

  var dataset = new recline.Model.Dataset({
    records: data
  });

  var $el = $('#myGrid');
  var grid = new recline.View.SlickGrid ({
    model: dataset,
    el : $el
  });

  grid.visible = true;
  grid.render();
});
</script>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS for relevant view components - here we just have grid -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="vendor/bootstrap/2.0.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slickgrid.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think you have to write the css <link> tags before the <script> tags

Comment: Thanks for suggesting, I tried that and its still doing the same.

Comment: Sorted this out, needed to include some more .css than listed on the tutorial.

Comment: Put your script tags in `<head>`, and definitely not before `<html>`.

Answer (score 1):

The CSS file that needs to be included is:

```
vendor/slickgrid/2.0.1/slick.grid.css
```